# How to read the contents of a file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that has multiple log files and I would like to generate the latest log file based on time and read the contents of that latest log file.

I have written the following, which gives only the latest log file and the contents inside that logs files are not generating

```
gci C:\Users\Documents\ArtifactsLogs\Test | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```

Please let me know if anything needs to be added.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to read the file into a variable use :

```
$a = Get-Content(gci C:\Users\Documents\ArtifactsLogs\Test | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1)
```

If you wish to display the contents on the console, just do:

```
$a
```